# Where do questions about the Untrusted programming game belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For those who don't know it [Untrusted, the Continuing Adventures of Dr. Eval](http://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/) is a nice "little" game where you play a Dr. (Dr. Eval) pictured as a (sometimes) green "`@`".

Your purpose is to get to the exit of each level.

So it is basically a game which should suggest http://gaming.stackexchange.com

But, brace yourselves, here's the kick : in *no* level will you be able to reach the exit just by "*playing*". You'll have to fiddle with the level's code which is displayed on the right part of the screen.

So all in all you'll have to develop bits of code to get to what you want which suggests http://stackoverflow.com

Which one is the best suited in this case ?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untrusted

Comment: I know there are questions there about the game, but if, for instance, I want to discuss pattern or beauty of implementation and such, isn't it more meaningfull to ask those tagged as javascript on stackOverflow ? I'm not looking for a place to ask questions but more on where it is it's most rightfull place.

Comment: Discussing the "beauty" of code is off-topic on SO. Specific questions about a programming pattern are ok on SO. It all depends on exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, when I say "beauty" what I mean is "maintainability", "readability", "consistency" and "robustness" and if SO is no place for those questions then my entire life is a lie ;)

Comment: Why on earth are you worried about any of that in the context of a hacking game?

Comment: Are my motivations relevant in any way ? But really I don't do "hacks", even if it were to be overkill I want to do things in a clean and orderly fashion.
Moreover none of the problems found in Untrusted's levels are genuinely novel and can always be related to other.
Just saying that I consider showing this game to people who's interest in programming I would like to cultivate and evaluate the quality of their answers.

Comment: @Ar3s The [Javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript) is probably the better place to discuss "pattern or beauty of implementation and such". Some of the Programmers chat regulars enjoy fooling around with Javascript, so you might want to try [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard) as well. Lastly, there's always the option to create a chatroom focused on the game.

Answer (score 3):

It's a game, and so is on topic for [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

IMO, it's off-topic for SO, because the fact that it's a game disqualifies it from being "a practical problem unique to software development".

While programming puzzles like Untrusted are definitely on topic for [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), the site is generally meant for *presenting* programming challenges, not for discussing them.  However, something like "Solve this Untrusted level in the least number of extra characters." could indeed be a valid challenge there, especially if it was a custom level you designed.  For some precedent, see e.g. the [manufactoria](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufactoria) tag.

There's also a very new site, [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) SE, that just recently entered public beta.  As is common for very new beta sites, their scope still seems to be in a bit of a state of flux, so I can't really say definitely whether any particular question about a programming game/puzzle would on topic there.  You could always give it a try, though (or ask on [their meta site](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/)).